# Keep velocity when using controller.jumpTo() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview

The method `jumpTo()` on a scrollController sets the velocity to 0, but I want to use jumpTo while the user is scrolling. Is there any way to change the controller's offset while keeping its velocity?

I use this as a  way to create a scrollView that scrolls infinitely in both directions. When the offset reaches the top, it jumps back down to its initial position. This is fine because the elements repeat.

Comment: are you using `ListView.builder`?

Comment: I am using `ListView.builder`

Comment: `child: Builder(
builder: (context) {
var data = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
return ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(data[index % data.length], textScaleFactor: 2,),
);
}
),`

Comment: I want a ScrollView that scrolls infinitely in both directions

Comment: I tried this. it is horribly inefficient and leads to performance issues